# Java is recognized but Javac is not recognized

Tags: java, windows

I recently installed Java but when I open the command line and I enter:

```
java -version
```

I get back:

```
C:\Users\Tim>java -version
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

But when I enter:

```
javac -version
```

I get back:

```
C:\Users\Tim>javac -version
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I added the following line to the end of my path in environment variables:

```
;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;
```

I installed this version:

```
jdk-8u60-windows-x64.exe
```

I use Windows 10. I have sought out multiple sources for help but none of them seem to be working. I think I've installed the right package as the name is JDK, it is for Windows on a 64 machine and java is found, but the compiler is not.  I'm trying to train on Java now, but I'm stuck here and can't go much further until I iron this out.  I appreciate any help.  Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked if you can access to the folder where `javac` is placed from PATH system environment variable?

Comment: What is the full value of your PATH? And where is the JDK installed? Is there a "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin"?

Comment: I open up the folder and javac.exe is present in the folder along with java.exe.

Comment: Try running this: `set "PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin"` in command prompt. And then try running javac again.

Comment: Okay, I ran it and then tried to open a .java file.

C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\Java>set "PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin
"

C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\Java>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_60

C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\Java>javac FirstExample.java
FirstExample.java:2: error: cannot find symbol
        public static void main(string[] args)
                                ^
  symbol:   class string
  location: class FirstExample
FirstExample.java:4: error: package system does not exist
        system.out.println("Hello World, I love you!");
              ^
2 errors

C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\Java>

Comment: So now it looks like you've a problem with your code. But it appears like the compiler is now working.

Comment: Thank you, this issue seems to be resolved now and javac is functioning,  The errors in the code were related to my failure to capitalize two of the words.  I am now having a new issue of 

Error: Could not find or load main class FirstExample 

when I enter in:  

java FirstExample

, but I am searching other threads for that now.  Again, thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You missed some steps. Go to variable environment and do the following:

**System Variables:**

- Edit **path** variable adding the following:

  ;C:\ProgramFiles\Java\Java_version\bin
- Create a new variable. Its name will be **classpath** and its value will be:
  ;C\ProgramFiles\Java\Java_Version\src.zip

**User Variables :**

- Create a variable called **path**, its value will be:
  C:\ProgramFiles\Java\Java_verson\bin
- Create a variable called **classpath** , its value will be:
  C\ProgramFiles\Java\Java_Version\src.zip

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem.. the solution is to remove all spaces from the java path. So instead of having it located at:

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60

**move the jdk folder to,**

for example: **JAVA_HOME = C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_60**

Then add the following line to the end of path in environment variables:

**C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;**

it worked for me :)